# Understanding certain parameters like "look back", "time steps" in LSTM ANN

Tags: python

I have been lately working on a self-project to forecast NO2 pollutant for the next hour and also the next 24 hours. As i am self learning, and have watched and read many documentations and guides for LSTM forecasting, I cant seem to grasp what does "time_steps" and "look back" do in LSTM models.

The dataset i am using is from DEFRA specifically forecasting NO2 in London.

with the dataset, I have used it on a model that was forked from github, while i have the model running accordingly and it did give me my predicted graph, i am unsure if it is showing me the right thing.

Since i was trying to forecast the next 24 hours of NO2 pollutant score in London. With my understanding my time_step must be 24 as I am trying to predict and forecast the next 24 hours. but changing timestep from 1 to 24 throws an error.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1e55XOXVMMbOYfpUgsk4VvrzkXXkQdW1o

Could anyone help clarify if what i am doing is correct. Based on my understanding, as i want to predict for the next 24 hours, wouldnt my time_steps need to be 24? Why is the error being prompted or is it that I am misunderstanding time_step?

Lastly, what does Look_back do?

Comment: Hey welcome, Can you post your code here so people can reproduce rather than an image? Thanks

Comment: Hi there, I have editted my post with my existing colab notebook